# Why modal does not working on Angular project?

Tags: html, angular, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I used bootstrap's modal on my Angular Project, but it does not work. How can I handle with this error? I also used [ngStyle] for handling this problem with angular variables as `[ngStyle]='display: displayValue'`. Also, it does not work.

Code as below:

```
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have any error in the console? What Bootstrap version are you using? 4 or 5?

Comment: I don't have any error. bootsrap 5

Comment: I suggest you use stackblitz.com to update your code

Answer (score 2):

use this code if you are using bootstrap 5

```html
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
    Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
    aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You said you use bootstrap 5, then change the *data-* attributes to *data-bs-* as explained in Javascript section inside the list of migration changes in bootstrap 5 (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/migration/).

Comment: I already tried it but it not not solution for this case at least mine.

Comment: Sure? It seems to run well.  Check here:  https://jsfiddle.net/2kLzpjqo/

Comment: yeah I am sure about it

Comment: @kira Maybe I missunderstood something about your problem, or maybe you should explain better what is not running in your modal, because it opens correctly after the **data-** to **data-bs-** change as demostrated here: https://jsfiddle.net/2kLzpjqo/.  I feel sorry to not be able to help you more with your current explanation.